Google OAuth2 flow not working with multiple redirect URIs
I am working on a Spring Boot application that uses Google SSO.
The Application YAML is configured as follows:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-name: Google
            client-id: XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret: XXXXXXXXX
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8069/login/oauth2/code/google
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
              - email
              - profile

An initial call to Google is made: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20profile&state=STATE_TOKEN&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8069/login/oauth2/code/google
When redirecting to http://localhost:8069/login/oauth2/code/google the authorization code generated and returned from google seems to not work for me when I attempt to retrieve the bearer (access) token. The POST method used for calling Google gives a response of 400 - Bad Request.
public BearerTokenResponse retrieveBearerTokens(String authCodeFromGoogle, OAuth2Configuration config) {
       
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(config.getBearerTokenEndpoint());

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        String refreshToken = null;

        post = httpHelper.addHeader(post, config.getAppClientId(), config.getAppClientSecret());
        urlParameters = httpHelper.getUrlParameters(authCodeFromGoogle, refreshToken, "", config);
        log.info("added parameters {}", urlParameters);


        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
            CloseableHttpClient CLIENT = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                    .build()).build();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = CLIENT.execute(post);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                closeResponse(response);
                return null;
             }
           }

    }

public List<NameValuePair> getUrlParameters(String authCode, OAuth2Configuration config) {
        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();

        if (config.getAuthorizationEndpoint().contains("google")) {
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", authCode));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", config.getAppClientId()));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", config.getAppClientSecret()));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", config.getAppRedirectUri()));
        }
      return urlParameters;
}

The strange thing is that this flow works perfectly fine when the Redirect URL is http://localhost:8069/google/oauth2redirect, which leads me to suspect that there is an issue when generating an authorization code for this specific redirect URL - which happens to be my oauth2successhandler.
I have added both URLs in the Google Dev Console as authorized redirect URIs, so I am not entirely sure what the issue could be - and I am NOT getting a URI_mismatch error...
I am also retrieving the authorization codes from the HttpServletRequest; which picks up the code for both http://localhost:8069/google/oauth2redirect and http://localhost:8069/login/oauth2/code/google.
Any help/suggestions would be welcome.
